# why inner time effect the filter result in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I am store time using unix timestamp, I am filter the data using this sql:

```
-- range of day but filter a minite
select *,date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')
from meow_report_pro.wallet_consume_record
where consume_time > 1623340800000
and consume_time < 1623427199999
and room_play_id = 48
and tenant_id = 5
and date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') = '2021-06-11 04:36'
```

I am checked all the time was in `2021-06-11 04:36`, this is the result snapshot:

[image]

but when I make time in the range `2021-06-11 04:36:00` - `2021-06-11 04:36:59` like this:

```
-- range by minites
select *,date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')
from meow_report_pro.wallet_consume_record
where consume_time >= 1623357360000
and consume_time <= 1623357419999
and room_play_id = 48
and tenant_id = 5
and date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(consume_time/1000), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') = '2021-06-11 04:36'
```

but the result is null!!!!! am I missing something? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/21 or else your criteria doesn't have a row

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';` and what timezone is set for the server?